# Dummy clip mapping problem

Tags: ableton-live

Ableton Brains needed!! I need to turn a device on when holding down a mapped midi key. I'm using dummy clip set to gate with intention of holding it down keeps device on, letting go turns it off. I've tried leaving the first part of the clip set to device off but letting go of the clip does not make the play head register as it being at the beginning and therefore does not turn the device back off when I let go of the button.. Any help gratefully received!